# Can't access Pokemon Go outside of Wi-Fi

Tags: pokemon-go

This happened to a friend of mine first, about a week before it hit me. All of a sudden, my Pokémon Go was having issues logging in. No matter how many times I tried, it couldn't authenticate. I tried re-logging to see if there was anything wrong with my credentials, to no effect. I re-installed the app, with the same outcome.

My friend then mentioned to me that the only time they are able to access the game is when their phone is connected to Wi-Fi, so following their advice, I tried again in Wi-Fi, and it worked.

I have an android phone, all of my other apps work, I have never had any connectivity issues with it.

Comment: Just to be sure, have you checked if your phone isn't blocking data usage on Pokemon Go? Typically you can check if it is under Settings ->Mobile Data

Comment: @Oak (very appropriate name BTW) yeah, it is allowed to use both

Comment: Also to be sure, have you checked that your phone isn't trying to connect to a wifi signal when you're trying to sign on? I've had this happen a few times, and it's usually because my phone has grabbed onto some "open" wifi signal that requires authentication. Turning off wifi fixes the issue for me.